# Expected constructor error only occurs at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, inheritance

I have a strange (in my eyes) issue with a Form and it's base Form's constructors. I am expecting an error from Visual Studio when I try and compile, but everything succeeds and it is only at runtime when the Form is created that an error occurs.

I have a base Form with the following constructors:

```
Public Sub New()

    'SNIP

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal businessObjectID As Integer)

    'SNIP

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal viewModel As BaseModel, ByVal childForm As Boolean)

    'SNIP

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal unitOfWork As IUnitOfWork)

    'SNIP

End Sub
```

I have a Form that inherits from the above base form whose constructor is this:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal viewModel As BaseModel, ByVal parentTaskModel As TaskModel)
     MyBase.New(viewModel)

     InitializeComponent()

     'SNIP

End Sub
```

The issue is that when the derived Form is created, I get an error saying that it can't cast type BaseModel to IUnitOfWork. Now I completely understand this and it is expected. However I would have expected Visual Studio to give me an error when writing the `MyBase.New(viewModel)` line in my code as the types don't match.

If I write `MyBase.New(string.Empty)` for example, I get an error about converting from String to Int, again understandable. However I can put any reference type in that line of code and it compiles without issue.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, or more likely why my brain is being stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of your file you should use

```
Option Strict On
```

Then you will get an error for implicit conversion.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329/en-us

> The Option Strict statement By default, the Visual Basic .NET or
>   Visual Basic compiler does not enforce strict data typing. To change
>   this default behavior, see the Change the Default Project Values
>   section.

Comment: This always cracks me up. The code lights up like a christmas tree :D

Comment: This project obviously never had this option on (unlike most of our projects), needless to say changing the project to `Strict On` broke the number of errors and took nearly 3 minutes to clear all the errors out when I set it to off again! Think I will specify it only on my new classes! Thanks very much for the answer.